# Sending email via Mailtrap in laravel 4.2 not sending

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm trying to test some emails within a laravel 4.2 app and have configured mail.php to use mailtrap

here's my mail.php config:

```
return array(
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
    'port' => 2525,
    'from' => array('address' => 'website@domain.co.uk', 'name'=>'Domain'),
    'encryption' => 'null',
    'username' => '12345XX',
    'password' => '12345XX',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
 );
```

I'm trying to use this within a development environment with a vagrant box (homestead)

I'm using a basic test script as follows to send a test email:

```
$data = array(
    'activationCode' => '123456789',
    'id' => 27,
    'user' => [
        'id'=>27,
        'first_name'=>'TEST USER',
        'last_name'=>'LAST NAME',
        'email'=>'test@domain.org.uk'
    ]
);

$firstResult = Mail::send('emails.auth.accessPending', $data, function ($message)  {
    $message
        ->to('email@domain.com')
        ->subject('website registration');
});
```

I get a `NULL` response and nothing appears in the mailtrap inbox.

What am I missing in either my configuration or script to get the app to send test emails?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have .env file those

```
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=your username
MAIL_PASSWORD=your pass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: Hi. the credentials have been added direct in the mail.php config file as above rather than in a .env file. I do use .env files in my later apps using laravel5 but havent updated this app for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - it was working - sort of. The reason there was no output because the mail config file for local development was set to `pretend`

Revealed by a quick check of the log file

Ta